# CtCI 16.8: Integer to English phrase in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, numbers-to-words

I'm a C++ beginner working through Cracking the Coding Interview. This is question 16.8:

> Given any integer, print an English phrase that describes the integer (e.g., "One Thou­sand, Two Hundred Thirty Four").

I have written a simple program, below, that I have confirmed works correctly to answer the question (note that I am ignoring the comma after "Thousand" in the example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// English Int: Given any integer, print an English phrase that describes the integer (e.g., "One Thou­sand, Two Hundred Thirty Four").

std::vector<int>         const magnitudes = {1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 1};
std::vector<std::string> const magnitude_names = {"Billion", "Million", "Thousand", ""};
std::vector<std::string> const number_names = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};
std::vector<std::string> const tens_group_names = {"", "", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"};
std::vector<std::string> const teens_names = {"Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"};


std::string name_for_group_of_3(int group);
std::string join_vector(std::vector<std::string> vector, std::string joiner);

// -1 -> "Negative One"
// 0 -> "Zero"
int main() {
    int input;
    while (1) {
        std::cout << "Input: ";
        std::cin >> input;

        if (input == 0) {
            std::cout << "Zero" << "\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> result;
        if (input < 0) {
            input *= -1;
            result.push_back("Negative");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < magnitudes.size(); i++) {
            int magnitude = magnitudes[i];
            if (input / magnitude > 0) {
                result.push_back(name_for_group_of_3(input / magnitude));
                result.push_back(magnitude_names[i]);
            }
            input %= magnitude;
        }

        std::cout << join_vector(result, " ") << "\n";
    }
}

// 0 -> ""
// 1 -> "One"
// 10 -> "Ten"
// 15 -> "Fifteen"
// 34 -> "Thirty Four"
// 456 -> "Four Hundred Fifty Six"
std::string name_for_group_of_3(int group) {
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // group should be 0...999
    if (group < 0 || group > 999) {
        throw "Bad grouping provided!";
    }

    // Handle hundreds
    if (group / 100 > 0) {
        result.push_back(number_names[group / 100] + " Hundred");
    }

    int double_digits = group % 100;

    // Handle special case for 11...19
    if (double_digits >= 10 && double_digits < 20) {
        result.push_back(teens_names[double_digits % 10]);
    }
    else {
        // Handle tens group
        if (double_digits / 10 > 0) {
            result.push_back(tens_group_names[double_digits / 10]);
        }

        // Handle ones
        if (double_digits % 10 > 0) {
            result.push_back(number_names[double_digits % 10]);
        }
    }

    return join_vector(result, " ");
}

std::string join_vector(std::vector<std::string> vector, std::string joiner) {
    std::string str_result;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        str_result += vector[i];
        if (i < vector.size()-1) {
            str_result += joiner;
        }
    }

    return str_result;
}
```

Notes & specific questions:

- Compiling with `g++ --std=c++11 main.cpp`
- I can run this on the first 10000 integers 0.15s on my '15 MacBook Pro, roughly 15µs per run. Is this reasonable performance?
- I opted to build vectors of strings, then join them together later, mostly to simplify dealing with the details of space placement. This feels cleaner to me, do you agree? Am I losing significant perf by using vectors vs. string concat?
- Is it evil to be modifying `input` as I do during `main`, with `input %= magnitude;`? It feels a bit odd to modify the original user input.
- Is `vector` a terrible argument name in `join_vector`?

I, of course, don't really know what else to ask - appreciate any & all pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General

Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`.  Warnings are preferable to runtime problems.  Sometimes I also compile with `-ftrapv` to avoid signed overflow.

You are doing much of the work inside `main`.  This violates the one responsibility principle.  Consider extracting a function `to_English` to do the actual work.  Also, your program becomes clueless after reaching EOF or invalid input.  A better `main` function looks like:

```
int main()
{
    for (int num; std::cout << "Input: ", std::cin >> num;)
        std::cout << to_English(num) << "\n";
}
```

In this case, the input process is simple, so I put it in the loop condition.  You may want to extract as a separate `get_number` function for more sophisticated input.

You do not need to store the strings in vectors.  Just concatenate them in place.

## Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

You are missing `#include <string>`.

```
std::vector<int>         const magnitudes = {1000000000, 1000000, 1000, 1};
```

Using `int` to hold values outside of the range \$-32\,768 \le n < 32\,768\$ is nonportable.  Use, for instance, `int_least32_t`, instead.  (You need to `#include <cstdint>`)  Write an alias for this to express the intent more explicitly: `using number_t = std::int_least32_t`, and use it consistently throughout the code.

```
std::string name_for_group_of_3(int group);
```

The name of the function is not entirely clear, but I cannot think of a better name either.  Maybe add a comment.

```
std::string join_vector(std::vector<std::string> vector, std::string joiner);
```

Don't pass `vector`s and `string`s by value.  Pass by const reference instead.  Also, `join_strings` may be a better name in my opinion.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
if (i < vector.size()-1) {
```

These lines trigger `-Wsign-compare`.  Use `std::size_t` or `std::vector<std::string>::size_type` instead of `int`.  [Use `++i` instead of `i++`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484492).

```
// group should be 0...999
if (group < 0 || group > 999) {
    throw "Bad grouping provided!";
}
```

Never throw a string literal.  Throw a `std::invalid_argument` instead.  Also, an assertion may be better for logical errors.